# Matlab mex can not build but gcc can

Tags: matlab, gcc, mex

I'm new to Matlab and was trying to build a C file. The code gets compiled fine with gcc (4.8.4 in 64-bit Ubuntu). But when I try to build with `mex`, it shows following error:

```
error: exponent has no digits
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The error is [in this file](http://pastebin.com/HEqYb6Ht). Complete [error log is here](http://pastebin.com/R2NEzftT).

When I compile the code using gcc, there are no errors. I do not provide any special arguments to gcc. To my knowledge, `mex` is using `gcc` so I do not understand why `mex` is failing to build the code.

I've little knowledge of C programming and any help is highly appreciated!

Edit:

To clarify more, I've got the source in two files:

- File 1 has the C code with a `main` function, and uses functions from [this
  file](http://pastebin.com/HEqYb6Ht) (which `mex` can not build).
- File 2 has the C code of the [`S-Function`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/what-is-an-s-function.html?refresh=true) which call's File 1's `main` function. File 2 has an `include` statement to include `File 1`.

When I said I can build using `gcc`, I just built `File 1` with this command: `gcc file1.c -o file1`. I think not building `File 2` with `gcc` has no impact here in my question, as only File 1 uses those functions from the file which `mex` can not build.

I used this command from Matlab `mex file2.c` to build and got the error.

Comment: Looks like mex is not supporting hex floats, `https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Hex-Floats.html`, this is line 982 where problem is. I guess you have to pass to `mex` option telling to use GNU extensions when building the code

Comment: Show the successful gcc command.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Thanks a lot. Can you tell me what are GNU extensions and probably, how to pass them to mex? If they're command line options for gcc, then it'll be easy to pass as per Matlab's docs, but I guess this is not the case.

Comment: gcc extensions are enabled using `-std=gnu++11` instead of `-std=c++11` (mutatis mutandis for other revisions of the standard)

Comment: @BenVoigt This is pure C, I believe, so most likely extension should be enabled by using -std=gnu99.

Comment: @giga Most likely you have to pass -std=gnu99 (or maybe gnu90) option to the compiler (mex is just a wrapper). UNnfortunately, I don't know how to do this now, my experience with matlab was long time ago

Comment: Direct quote "You may also select an extended version of the C language explicitly with -std=gnu90 (for C90 with GNU extensions), -std=gnu99 (for C99 with GNU extensions)"

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Thanks again. I should be able to do this, I'll check soon and post here.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22236710/2778484) for an example on how to do it.  It's basically `mex -v -largeArrayDims CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS -std=gnu99" mexSouce.c `.  But GCC 4.4.x seems really old.

Comment: @chappjc My mistake in typing. I'm actually using 4.8.4. Any idea why I do need to explicitly enable extension for `mex`, while I do NOT need to enable them when directly calling `gcc` from a terminal?

Comment: As I said in my other post, the default config `mex` has usually been ANSI C so it depends what gcc considers ANSI C.

Comment: @chappjc Thank you very much, this works without any issue!

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux you might like to summarize this discussion as an answer?

Comment: @giga Glad it worked.  Consider acknowledging the referenced post.

Comment: @chappjc Sure I will. Would you consider writing an answer so that I can accept it? If you don't have time, I will write an answer.

Comment: Done.  Thanks for that.  I've already done in kind.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C code, you probably need to enable GNU extensions for C99 (`-std=gnu99`).  As described in [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22236710/2778484) on enabling C99, to pass this to `mex`:

```
mex -v -largeArrayDims CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS -std=gnu99" mexSouce.c
```

The reason the default does not work is because `mex` likes to choose the [ANSI standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C), which is often not the newest.